# How to kill a bunch of jobs based on ps output?

Tags: bash, command-line, process, zsh, kill

Here is output from `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep blob
ubuntu    4286  0.0  0.1  34748  9592 ?        S    Jan14   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pynt start_blob_reader
ubuntu    4287  0.0  0.1  34748  9596 ?        S    Jan14   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pynt start_blob_reader
ubuntu    4288  0.0  0.0   4444   656 ?        S    Jan14   0:00 /bin/sh -c python -m blob_manager blob
ubuntu    4289  1.2  0.2  65512 20668 ?        S    Jan14 1974:18 python -m blob_manager blob
ubuntu    4290  0.0  0.0   4444   656 ?        S    Jan14   0:00 /bin/sh -c python -m blob_manager blob
ubuntu    4291  1.2  0.2  65404 20624 ?        S    Jan14 1978:24 python -m blob_manager blob
ubuntu   19849  0.0  0.0  10464   896 pts/0    S+   05:43   0:00 grep blob
```

What is the easiest to kill these jobs (except `19849` because it is the `grep` process itself) via shell scripting?

Either `bash` or `zsh` is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pkill`:

```
pkill blob
```

That would kill all processes matching the pattern `blob`.

Another approach would be `killall`, but you should call it with `-r` so that the pattern is interpreted as a regex:

```
killall -r blob
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get all the PIDs and kill 'em all:

```
kill $(ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep java |awk '{print $2}'|tr '\n' ' '); echo
```

or make it more verbose:

```
netikras@netikras-PC ~ $ #ps -ef |grep -v grep |grep java |while read line; do echo "$line" |awk '{$1=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=""; print "Killing: "$0"\n"}'; kill $(echo $line|awk '{print $2}') && echo KILLED || echo FAILED ; done
netikras@netikras-PC ~ $
```